# Configurar Cake bake para Versão 2.x do Cake

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2

Eu tenho uma libary do Cake 2.3 no meu Ubuntu 13.10 configurado e rodando normalmente.

Quando tento usar o cake bake, ele assume automáticamente o Cake 1.3

```
Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.14 Console
```

Pergunta: Como configuro o cake bake para usar a versão 2.3 do Cake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente chamar pelo seguinte comando

```
/var/www/<caminho do seu cake>/app/Console/cake
```

ou

```
cd /var/www/<caminho do seu cake>/app/Console/
php cake.php
```

Essas são duas possibilidades de chamar o seu `bake`, sempre confira o caminho do seu [cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp) para garantir que está chamando a aplicação correta

Comment: Olá Erlon, obrigado pela resposta. Quando executei o primeiro comando, apresetou a mesma mensagem: Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.14 Console.

No segundo comando já apresentou o correto. Welcome to CakePHP v2.3.4 Console. Obrigado pela Ajuda!